# Using Windows 7 taskbar features in PyQt

Tags: python, windows-7, pyqt, pyqt4, taskbar

I am looking for information on the integration of some of the new Windows 7 taskbar features into my PyQt applications.

Specifically if there already exists the possibility to use the new progress indicator ([see here](http://www.petri.co.il/wp-content/uploads/new_win7_taskbar_features_10.gif)) and the quick links (www.petri.co.il/wp-content/uploads/new_win7_taskbar_features_8.gif).

If anyone could provide a few links or just a "not implemented yet", I'd be very grateful.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As quark said, the functionality is not in Qt 4.5, but you can call the windows API directly from Qt. Its a little bit of work though.

1. The new taskbar API is exposed through COM, so you can't use ctypes.windll . You need to create a .tlb file to access the functions. Get the interface definition for ITaskbarList from [this forum post](http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?s=6352ade29ce66f2b51506c64e455d2f4&showtopic=716968&st=0&p=590434472&#entry590434472) , or from the windows SDK. Save it to a file called e.g. TaskbarLib.idl .
2. Create the .tlb file. You'll probably need the Windows SDK, or get an IDL compiler from somewhere else.

   ```
   midl TaskbarLib.idl /tlb TaskbarLib.tlb
   ```
3. Load the .tlb (you need the Win32 Extensions for Python, http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html):

   ```
   import comtypes.client as cc
   cc.GetModule("TaskbarLib.tlb")
   ```
4. Create the TaskbarList object. The function for setting the progress bar is in the interface ITaskbarList3:

   ```
   import comtypes.gen.TaskbarLib as tbl
   taskbar = cc.CreateObject(
       "{56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090}",
       interface=tbl.ITaskbarList3)
   ```
5. Now you can call the API functions:

   ```
   taskbar.HrInit()
   taskbar.SetProgressValue(self.winId(),40,100)
   ```

Here's a [complete example script](http://pastebin.com/f7ed294a8).
Sources:
    [1](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Message/python-win32/3757531)
    [2](http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?s=6352ade29ce66f2b51506c64e455d2f4&showtopic=716968&st=0&p=590434472&#entry590434472)

Answer (score 5):

There is a Qt add-on that implements all the Windows 7 taskbar extensions. It is called [Q7Goodies](http://www.strixcode.com/q7goodies/). It comes with a PyQt bindings, so this is probably the easiest way to take advantage of Windows 7 features in PyQt.

Answer (score 3):

Not implemented in Qt 4.5, but [in the works for Qt 4.6](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/10/qt-46-promises-to-deliver-windows-7-maemo-and-s60-support.ars) it appears.  PyQt won't wrap 4.6 until Qt 4.6 is officially released, but you can play with the [4.6 snapshot](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6-snapshot/)s or checkout the [Qt repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt) and see if the C++ version supports the features you want.  If it does then PyQt 4.6 will support it as well.

Added: The [list of 4.6 features](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6-snapshot/qt4-6-intro.html) doesn't show explicit Windows 7 support, but that doesn't mean it won't have what you want, since, at least if I understand correctly, its likely they would fold that functionality into the existing widget.