# Windows progress bar in python's Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, progress-bar, tkinter, python-2.6

Is there any way in python's Tkinter, bwidget or anything similar to show a Windwos' default progress bar?
I already know the bwidget.ProgressBar, but it produces an ugly progress bar while I mean showing a valid windows progress bar - the green, glowing one:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/unledtph.png/

I need it because that way Windows will automatically show the progress of my program in the task bar. Plus, it looks better.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a modern (2.7+) version of Tkinter you can try the [ttk.ProgressBar](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Progressbar) which is part of Tkinter.

Comment: +1 Thanks for putting me straight on my out-of-date misconceptions.

Answer (score 8):

You can install the [pyttk](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttk) module separately.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
root = Tk()
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack(side="bottom")
progressbar.start()
root.mainloop()
```

As far as the taskbar functionality, that is not available in Tkinter yet (at least to the best of my knowledge).  You'll need to make use of the Windows API for that.  Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736394/using-windows-7-taskbar-features-in-pyqt) is for PyQt, the answers should prove helpful.  Hope it gets you started.

Comment: Wow! A lot better!
But it still doesn't look exactly the way Windows shows it. And therefor it doesn't appear in my taskbar too. Do you know a way to improve it?

Comment: @speller Updated my answer with some more info for your taskbar question.

Comment: Well OK - very useful. But I care more about the progressbar glowing like a normal windows bar - Do you know how to make that happen?

Comment: How do you make it stop when completed?

Comment: @JShoe: Call `progressbar.stop()`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would appear to be to use themed Tk with the tkinter.ttk module included in Python 2.7 and 3.1. The [Progressbar](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Progressbar) widget is what you want.

Since you appear to be considering other frameworks you might look at Qt or wxWidgets which look native and have excellent Python bindings.

Comment: The Problem is I already have a full up-and-running application that uses Tkinter - All I want to do is add a prog. bar to it. If I wanted to know what python module should I use for GUI programming - I would have asked that very question.

Comment: @speller Both answers point you to tkinter.ttk. You also started your question "Is there any way in python's Tkinter, bwidget or anything similar" which I took to mean that the answer was not restricted to Tkinter. Anyway, Bryan has put me right and it does indeed seem that modern Tkinter is much better.

Comment: The title clearly says "python's Tkinter". bwidget works with Tkinter and only comes to add features to it, but I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. Anyway - I understand that you both don't know any way to do it with 2.6's Tkinter - so thnx :)

Comment: @speller I'm only trying to help. Comments like "If I wanted to know what python module should I use for GUI programming - I would have asked that very question" and "The title clearly says python's Tkinter" rather put me off trying to help.

Comment: Well I'm sorry - I didn't mean to offend you