# Integrate Qt with Windows 7 taskbar using python?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, taskbar, pyside

I'm looking for a way to using some of the Windows 7 task bar features - specifically progressbar and jump lists - in a python application that uses Qt for the UI. The questions I've seen on SO are all 1-2 years old and either say Qt isn't there yet but the next version will have it (which has since been released) or point me to [Q7Goodies](http://www.strixcode.com/q7goodies/) which I'd prefer not to use for cost reasons.

Does anyone know if Qt and a python binding, either PyQt or PySide, can interact with the Windows 7 taskbar?

I am using Python 2.7.x and Qt 4.6. I can upgrade to 4.7 if needed, I can't move up to Python 3.x just yet.

Comment: I suggest you add C++ too. may be some core way of doing will give some clue on how this can be done in python way

Comment: I've found some similar issue.
[Please, see for related question here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736394/using-windows-7-taskbar-features-in-pyqt

Answer (score 2):

For C++ there is something called EcWin7, just look: [http://code.google.com/p/dukto/source/browse/trunk/src/ecwin7.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/dukto/source/browse/trunk/src/ecwin7.cpp?r=64)

Maybe it's not so hard to make Python bindings for it but I'm not sure.

Hope it helps anyhow :)