# wxPython and windows 7 taskbar

Tags: python, api, user-interface, windows-7, taskbar

For brevity's sake: I'm trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736394/using-windows-7-taskbar-features-in-pyqt/1744503#1744503) with wxPython, but I'm struggling to fit that code into a script based on wxPython.

My simple PyQt test code works fine. Here it is:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from threading import Thread
import time
import sys
import comtypes.client as cc
import comtypes.gen.TaskbarLib as tbl

TBPF_NOPROGRESS = 0
TBPF_INDETERMINATE = 0x1
TBPF_NORMAL = 0x2
TBPF_ERROR = 0x4
TBPF_PAUSED = 0x8

cc.GetModule("taskbar.tlb")
taskbar = cc.CreateObject("{56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090}", interface=tbl.ITaskbarList3)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.progress_bar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.progress_bar)
        self.progress_bar.setRange(0, 100)

        self.progress = 0

        self.show()

        thread = Thread(target=self.counter)
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()

    def counter(self):
        while True:
            self.progress += 1
            if self.progress > 100:
                self.progress = 0

            time.sleep(.2)

            self.progress_bar.setValue(self.progress)

            taskbar.HrInit()
            hWnd = self.winId()
            taskbar.SetProgressState(hWnd, TBPF_ERROR)        
            taskbar.SetProgressValue(hWnd, self.progress, 100)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But, when I try to execute the wxPython counterpart, the taskbar doesn't work as expected. Here's the wxPython code:

```py
import wx
import time
import comtypes.client as cc
import comtypes.gen.TaskbarLib as tbl
from threading import Thread

TBPF_NOPROGRESS = 0
TBPF_INDETERMINATE = 0x1
TBPF_NORMAL = 0x2
TBPF_ERROR = 0x4
TBPF_PAUSED = 0x8

cc.GetModule("taskbar.tlb")
taskbar = cc.CreateObject("{56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090}", interface=tbl.ITaskbarList3)

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self.panel)
        self.gauge.SetValue(0)

        self.progress = 0

        self.Show()

        thread = Thread(target=self.counter)
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()

    def counter(self):
        while True:
            self.progress += 1
            if self.progress > 100:
                self.progress = 0

            time.sleep(.2)

            self.gauge.SetValue(self.progress)

            taskbar.HrInit()
            hWnd = self.GetHandle()

            taskbar.SetProgressState(hWnd, TBPF_ERROR)
            taskbar.SetProgressValue(hWnd, self.progress, 100)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test")
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
app.MainLoop()
```

In particular I think the issue is due to the wxWindow window handle (hWnd) method, that differ from its Qt equivalent, the former returning an integer and the latter a "sip.voidptr object".

The problem is that I already wrote the whole code (1200+ lines) with wxPython, thus i can't re-write it to use Qt (not to talk about the different licenses).

What do you think about it? Should I give up?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

**EDIT**

Thanks to Robert O'Connor, now it works. However, I still can't get why `GetHandle` returns an integer while `winId` returns an object. In the .idl file the argument hwnd is declared as `long` in all the function definitions. Maybe this is a simple question too ;) Any Ideas?

Comment: PySide is the same as PyQT with a better license...

Comment: Thanks, I will consider it in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following line:

```
hWnd = self.panel.GetId()
```

You want to use `GetHandle()` instead of `GetId()`.

**Edit:** This was originally posted as a comment, but I suppose it would be more appropriate for me to repost as an answer.

Regarding the edit to your question: If it now works I guess there isn't a problem anymore ;) Okay, seriously though..

Ints and Longs are unified in Python and if I had to guess comtypes might be doing some coercion in the background. I don't know if it's necessary to worry about such details when dealing with comtypes in general, but it doesn't seem to matter much in this case.

Now I have no experience with PyQT, but in Python you can define special methods on objects such as `__int__` and `__long__` to emulate, well, Ints and Longs. If I had to guess, the object you're getting in PyQT defines one of those methods.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about GetHandle, but forgot to edit the code after various test I made :) The fact is that now it works... I've done a lot of confusion with my code, my fault. I edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: I did want to point out that I appreciate you asking this question. I've had a few reasons for wanting to use the Taskbar features and now I don't have to work at figuring out _how_. Now I have to add one more reason to my "List of Reasons for Needing an IDL Compiler" list.

Comment: Well, glad I could help and thank you again! I was definitely not thinking about the __int__ method. I checked out ("dir-ed" the object instance) and found it: `int(hWnd)` returns a plausible value. It all seems to be clearer now :)