# PyQt4 & Windows 7 Thumbnail Toolbar

Tags: python, pyqt, aero

How can I add some **thumbnail toolbar** buttons to a `QMainWindow` with PyQt4, without using native code (ctypes and similar are fine, but not creating a DLL from another language)?

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't break the platform independence of my application (i.e. on Linux it should just do nothing).

[image: Thumbnail Toolbar]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC420540.png))</sub>

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1744503/790439) and then read the [microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try... Do you know how does this behave on Windows XP/Vista?

Comment: I cannot compile the TLB because I'm developing under Linux and I don't have admin rights on the Windows 7 machine I use for testing. Can you compile the file in [the previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1744503/790439) for me? Thanks

Comment: I honestly don't know how this behaves in xp/vista, I'd guess that it fails silently. For the tlb just Google `taskbar.tlb`, you'll find a bunch of github repos that are using it and you can try those. I currently don't have the Windows 7sdk installed but I can do it if the other option fails. just let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it works. On XP `CreateObject` throws a `WindowsError`, which I catch and ignore. I managed to set the progress bar, but now I have trouble passing non-Python types to `ITaskbarList3` functions, specifically `HICON`, `LPTHUMBBUTTON` and `RECT*`. Do you know a soultion?

Comment: for the rect you can try `win32gui.rectangle`, for the hicon go into your `python for Windows` documentation and do a search for hicon, you'll see various functions that return a `hicon`. I can't find anything on `lpthumbbutton`, you'll have to try Google for that one, or ask a new question.

Comment: I found that I can use the structs (`RECT` and `THUMBBUTTON`) as Python classes by using `comtypes.gen.TaskbarLib.RECT` and `comtypes.gen.TaskbarLib.THUMBBUTTON`. No solution for `HICON` yet.

Comment: @LordSpectre How did you initialise `RECT` and `THUMBBUTTON`? I've had no success with those.

Comment: I didn't use them in my application yet (I need `HICON` too), but as far as I remember I was able to instantiate them normally (`rect=comtypes.gen.TaskbarLib.RECT()`). I'll check when I have access to my Win7 test machine.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud read this webpage

http://nicug.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/windows-7-taskbar-extensions-in-qt.html

good luck