# Python + Tkinter Windows 7 taskbar progress

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, progress

I want to show the progress of my app in a taskbar button.
I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1744503/2575039) as a reference.

Here's an example of what I do:

```py
import tkinter

import comtypes.client as cc
cc.GetModule("TaskbarLib.tlb")

import comtypes.gen.TaskbarLib as tbl
taskbar = cc.CreateObject(
    "{56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090}",
    interface=tbl.ITaskbarList3)

class gui(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = gui(root)

    taskbar.HrInit()
    taskbar.SetProgressValue(root.winfo_id(),40,100)

    root.mainloop()
```

But I see no progress on a taskbar button. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use my library [PyTaskbar](https://pypi.org/project/PyTaskbarProgress/) like this:

```
import tkinter
import PyTaskbar # the module

class gui(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = gui(root)

    taskbar_progress = PyTaskbar.Progress(root.winfo_id()) # Instantiate a new progress object
    taskbar_progress.init() # Initialize the progress bar
    taskbar_progress.setState("normal") # Set the progress bar state to normal (Available: loading, normal, warning, error)
    taskbar_progress.setProgress(50) # Set the progress bar value to 50%

    root.mainloop()
```

It automatically handles all the things you need to do with comtypes, making it MUCH easier.

Docs: [Here](https://github.com/somePythonProgrammer/PyTaskbar/blob/main/docs.md)

Disclaimer: this library was made by me.

Answer (score 4):

The tab needs to be activated. Add `taskbar.ActivateTab(root.winfo_id())` after `taskbar.HrInit()`.
In tkinter is better to use `int(root.wm_frame(), 16)` instead `root.winfo_id()` because otherwise near tkinter tab will appear a python tab with a progressbar.
At the end `taskbar.SetProgressState(HWND, TBPF_NOPROGRESS)` should be called to remove the progressbar.

The flags need to be defined. Eg. `TBPF_NOPROGRESS = 0`.
Check Microsoft's webpage for more options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I know this is an old question but maybe someone will find it useful.

Comment: It's also quite important to initialize `HWND` **after** you start rendering the window — because the `wm_frame()` value changes. So you should either init your `taskbar` on the run, or call `root.update()` once before you call `wm_frame()`.

Answer (score -3):

If I'm correct I think you need to .pack or .grid it

Comment: Here, taskbar is a COM object, not a tkinter widget. I don't want do place it anywhere on a window (and I couldn't even if I needed to - it does not have these methods).