# Show progress on taskbar icon

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, progress

I placed a progressbar in my tkinter GUI but it is not showing the progress on the taskbar icon. Like when I copy and paste in Windows:
[image: Windows File Explorer progressbar]

How can I implement this in my Tkinter GUI?

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
    
root = Tk()
    
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack(side="bottom")
progressbar.start()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Currently, the progress bar looks like this:

[image: No taskbar progress]

How to add progress behind the icon on the Windows taskbar?

Using Python `3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python + Tkinter Windows 7 taskbar progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607415/python-tkinter-windows-7-taskbar-progress)

Comment: I see you're using windows 10 but this will hopefully still help.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I am neither using Windows 10 nor 7 . I am using Windows 8.

Comment: Ah, sorry. In any case, does linked question help?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I receive this error: http://dpaste.com/2BV4V5R

Comment: 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl 64 bit.

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit DLL?

Comment: No.............

Comment: Tru using https://github.com/N3RDIUM/PyTaskbar